# Nextjs app renders server side data twice every refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm building a quiz app in typescript and nextjs. The page uses serverside rendering to fetch all of the questions in the database and then runs a function in the page to create an array with all of the questions picked at random. However for some reason the app fetches the data twice meaning that the array with random questions is generated twice and as the arrays are random its different everytime. This means that I get the "Text content does not match server-rendered HTML." error whenever the page is loaded.

Any advice on how to fix this issue.

The console showing the generated random quetion array looks like this:

[image: As you can see one time the array is rendered in conjugation.tsx which is the name of the page and then another render is made in react devtools backend .js]

As you can see one time the array is rendered in conjugation.tsx which is the name of the page and then another render is made in react devtools backend .js

The file itself looks something like this:

```
const Quiz = ({questions}:{questions: IQuestion[]}) => {

let currentQuestion = 0;
let numberOfQuestions = 5;
let randomQuestionsArray = [];

const generateRandomQuestionsArray = () => {
   for (let i = 0; randomQuestionsArray.length < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
      randomQuestionsArray.push(questions[randomNumber])
   }
}

generateRandomQuestionsArray()

return (
      <div>{randomQuestionsArray[currentQuestion]}</div>
)

}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    let { data } = await supabase.from('questions').select()

    return {
        props: {
            questions: data
        },
    }
}
```

Can anyone here help?

Thanks

Comment: Could be strict mode?

Comment: I've already changed the nextjs config  to {reactStrictMode: false}

Comment: Don't push data into the array - it can handle updates wrong(and will). Do something or mix of: 1) const randomQuestionsArray = generateRandomQuestions(questions, 5); and generateRandomQuestions should return an array and can be outside of the component; 2) use React.useState to handle state changes - as I see currentQuestions would also update; - changes handle in useEffect 3) from getServerSideProps return 5 random questions